# Set current checkbox value in "$on('$destroy')" in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-change

I am new in angular js. I am implementing checkbox and also I want to prevent reset checkbox after reloading and after navigate to another page. Right now when I  reloading the page then checkbox will reset. So I am using $on("$destroy") saving the state. But I am not able to set checkbox current value with $on("$destroy").

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" class="checkbox style-0"
       name="mycheckbox" ng-model="mycheckbox" data-ng-change="confirm()" />
```

**ANGULAR CONTROLLER:**

```
$scope.confirm= function(){
  if($scope.mycheckbox== false)
  {
    alert("inside unchecked");
  }

  else{
    alert("inside checked");
  }
}
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){ 
  sessionStorage.date=matchDate;
  sessionStorage.maxValue=realValue;
  sessionStorage.minValue=normalValue;
})
```

How to set current checkbox value checked or unchecked in $on(destroy). I am already set some value in $on(destroy), But in checkbox case I am confused. So please share your idea. Your answer valuable for me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$on('$destroy')` means the controller is going away because the page is unloaded. You will have to store the current state of the checkbox like you are storing the other data. Then in the controller initialization you can check if there is a stored value for the checkbox and if there is use that to initialize the checkbox instead of the default value.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
  $scope.checkbox = (sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty('checkbox') ? sessionStorage.checkbox : false);

  $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){ 
    sessionStorage.date=matchDate;
    sessionStorage.maxValue=realValue;
    sessionStorage.minValue=normalValue;
    sessionStorage.checkbox=$scope.checkbox;
  })
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. could you provide some sample code Because I am new in angular.

Comment: Its giving me only false value of checkbox